# How to find the probability of at least 5 being rolled on a 6-sided die

Tags: probability

This is a simple question, but I'm not sure how to show my work for this problem.

In a fair six-sided die toss, what's the probability of 5 showing at least once?

The answer should be $$\frac{11}{36}$$ but I'm not completely sure as to how to get this answer. If you can just write out a basic formula or give hints on this, that would be great. The "at least" always tends to mess me up.

Any question similar to mine please link it in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: question in title is different than question in information and the question in information is inexact as it doesn't say how many times you roll the dice etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the probability $p$ to have at least one $5$ in TWO rolls? 
Think to complement, that is $1-p$: what is the probability to have no $5$ at all in two rolls?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean that the die is rolled twice. Then letting 
$A$ ={ see a 5 on first roll}, $B$= { see a 5 on second roll}, we can use 
$$ P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$ 
$P(A)=P(B)=1/6$. I'll let you figure out the last bit.